# How to calculate SUM of specific row range based on date?

Tags: google-sheets

How to calculate the remaining amount to spend for a specific day (that day is today).

So, I have the budget for one month (let's say 1000$).
My daily spending is 32.25$.
If I spent 20$ today, is there a possibility to see how much is left for today?

So basically we have 3 steps.

1. SUM all transactions from today's date
2. Subtract from the daily budget(I can put it in a separate cell, or I can put it in the same cell)
3. Show the result in cell

   Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AhreVRWJyMoG5JR-qvtK3Jq9K98G3L_-oIn6ju0Ssmk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you share an editable sample google sheet, it can be shown how to do it.

Comment: My apologies becouse i didn't include sheet.

Comment: Yes it is possible to search sum of all today's transactions and then subtract that from the daily budget as you ask.  But it will not be possible (for me) without a link to a share SAMPLE of the sheet.  not the real thing, just a sample.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thank you for your help @MattKing, included sample of sheet. I am sorry for mistakes, i am new commer here :) And hope that anybody else need something like this. Cheers.

Comment: I see that in your sheet it says _"Set your starting balance in cell `L8`"_. But it is in cell `L9`.  Also, you say _"Subtract from daily budget"_.  How do you calculate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Edited answer**

*(following OP's comment on the sheet: "Daily budget would be determined by Planned expenses (`C22` cell) divided by number of days in month.")*

Your final needed formula would be:

```
=(SUMIF(Transactions!B5:B44;"="&(TODAY());Transactions!C5:C44))-
       C22/(EOMONTH(TODAY();0)-(EOMONTH(TODAY();-1)))
```

To summarize, these are **the 3 formulas you will need** to get your expected result:

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|      We used A-B=C      |                             Formulas                             | Test Result |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| A. today's transactions | =SUMIF(Transactions!B5:B44;"="&(TODAY());Transactions!C5:C44)    | ₩360.700    |
| B. daily budget         | =C22/(EOMONTH(TODAY();0)-(EOMONTH(TODAY();-1)))                  | ₩34.448     |
| C. remaining for today  | =(SUMIF(Transactions!B5:B44;"="&(TODAY());Transactions!C5:C44))- |             |
|                         |    C22/(EOMONTH(TODAY();0)-(EOMONTH(TODAY();-1)))                | ₩326.252    |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

***Note***: One may have to replace `;` with `,` according to the sheet,s locale.

---

**Original answer**

If I understand you well, the formula you would need is:

*`=(SUM all transactions from today's date)-(daily budget)`*

```
=(SUMIF(Transactions!B5:B44;"="&TODAY();Transactions!C5:C44))-(daily budget)
```

You can place the formula in cell `L10` *(Today left)* to see the result.

***Note***: I don't understand what you mean or how you calculate your "daily budget" so I leave this part for you.
Still. If you need further assistance please let us know.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you very much @marikamitsos for making this answer! This was all i needed. And also this was really helpful for my knowlage with google sheets. I understand now how to deal with date in sheets.